# How to enable dynamic scripting in ElasticSearch with its gem?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I'm getting the error `nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled];` because of this aggregation I'm making:

```
agg :category_aggregation do
  {
    terms: {
      script: "doc['categories.id'].value + '|' + doc['categories.name'].value",
      size: 30
    }
  }
end
```

I'm using the official elasticsearch gem and also tried with chewy but couldn't find how to enable the dynamic_search anywhere.

ElasticSearch version in my OS X: 1.5.2 installed with homebrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dynamic scripting can only be enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/modules-scripting.html#_enabling_dynamic_scripting) from the `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file in your ES cluster.

Add this to the file on every node and restart your cluster:

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

**UPDATE**

Since you've installed ES via homebrew, you can find the `elasticsearch.yml` file in `/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.5.2/config`

Comment: I've read it before but I couldn't find this file anywhere on my machine and couldn't even find where should I create it with a default content. So I thought that maybe the gem could also have a config file that would overlap the server configuration.

Can you tell me where to find this file? Finder didin't find the file. I've installed ES with homebrew.

Comment: Yup, the file was right there. Don't know why finder didn't find it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help! I don't trust the finder :-) Note that if you run `brew info elasticsearch` it will tell you where the installation folder is located.